# High power and double precision

Tags: algorithm, math, numeric, exponent

How do you solve the below equation in some programming language of your choice?

```
(1-1/X)^Y
```

Easy!

But how about when X & Y are very big and X>>Y

e.g.

```
(1-1/X)^Y
where 
X = 10^40
Y = 10^12
```

Looks like it should be a simple enough problem, but getting around the double precision problem before applying the power is something I was not able to figure out.

Comment: I believe it is language dependent - in some languages, I believe you would use some library that implements fixed point arithmeric, like [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) in java.

Comment: Use wolframalpha.com to expand into a series representation that does not have any X^Y terms, and then compute as many terms of the series as necessary to achieve your desired precision.

Comment: To the closevoter: How is this off topic?

Answer (score 4):

Well, `(1 - 1/X)^Y = exp(Y*log(1 - 1/X))`. If `X` is very large, and much larger than `Y`, you can approximate the logarithm with

```
log(1 - 1/x) = -1/x -1/(2*X^2) + O(1/X^3)
```

and calculate

```
exp(-(Y/X+ Y/(2*X*X)))
```

If `X` isn't that much larger than `Y`, using a third or even fourth term of the Taylor series of the logarithm may be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Using [GNU Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/index.html) the calculations are approximate:

```
octave:1> x = 10^40
x =  1.0000e+40
octave:2> y = 10^12
y =  1.0000e+12
octave:3> (1-1/x)^y
ans =  1

octave:8> exp(-(y/x + y /(2*x*x)))
ans =  1
```

Provided that the calculation made by Daniel Fischer is correct, the code to calculate `exp(-(Y/X+ Y/(2*X*X)))` in **Java** using **BigDecimal** is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal(10,MathContext.UNLIMITED).pow(40);
    BigDecimal y = new BigDecimal(10,MathContext.UNLIMITED).pow(12);

    BigDecimal twoXSquared = new BigDecimal(2,MathContext.UNLIMITED).multiply(x).multiply(x);
    BigDecimal yDividedByTwoXSquared = y.divide(twoXSquared);

    BigDecimal yDividedByX = y.divide(x);


    BigDecimal exponent = new BigDecimal(-1,MathContext.UNLIMITED).multiply(yDividedByX.add(yDividedByTwoXSquared));
    System.out.println(exponent.toEngineeringString());

    BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal(Math.E,MathContext.UNLIMITED).pow(exponent.intValue());

    System.out.println(result.toEngineeringString());

}
```